# Select highest percent first php sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following sql which selects the most recurring row first based on the column "reported"

```
 $datan = mysql_query("
   SELECT *, COUNT(reported) AS ct
   FROM profile_reports
   WHERE open = '1'
   GROUP BY reported
   ORDER BY ct DESC
   LIMIT 1
 ") or die(mysql_error());
```

I want my sql to also check which 'reporter' (each is a number associated with a user) has the best percentage of useful reports, which is determined this way:

```
((raction > 0 AND raction < 99 AND open = '0' AND reporter = 'reporter') / (reporter = 'reporter' AND open = '0')) * 100
```

...and show the rows with highest percentage first. It's a little tricky because no initial reporter is set.

Here's a sample table:

```
+----+----------+----------+-------+----------+
| id | reporter | reported | open  |  raction |
+----+----------+----------+-------+----------+
|  1 |       24 |    26    |  0    |  3       |
|  2 |       24 |    23    |  0    |  0       |
|  3 |       24 |    29    |  1    |          |
|  4 |       12 |    29    |  0    |  4       |
|  5 |       12 |    29    |  1    |          |
|  6 |       24 |    21    |  1    |  0       |
+----+----------+----------+-------+----------+
```

I want it to see that there are more reports about user 29(column: reported), then check which reporting user(column: reporter) has the best percentage (based on the line of code above), in this case user 12, and display their report

Comment: Can you show some sample data and the return data you would like from it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its actually pretty easy in just take the sums of your conditions and divide. In order to get the "Reported" correctly you'll need to use an inline view to find the highest report.

```
SELECT pr.*, 
       ( Sum(pr.raction > 0 
             AND pr.raction < 99 
             AND pr.open = '0' 
             AND pr.reported = t.reported) / Sum(pr.reported = t.reported 
                                                 AND pr.open = '0') ) * 100 AS 
       usefull 
FROM   profile_reports pr, 
       (SELECT reported 
        FROM   profile_reports 
        WHERE  open = '1' 
        GROUP  BY reported 
        ORDER  BY Count(reported) DESC 
        LIMIT  1) t 
GROUP  BY reporter 
ORDER  BY usefull DESC 
LIMIT  1
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c06d4/20)

Output

```
| ID | REPORTER | REPORTED | OPEN | RACTION | USEFULL |
-------------------------------------------------------
|  4 |       12 |       29 |    0 |       4 |     100 |
```

I haven't done everything for you.  You will have to decide what to do if the divisor is zero

Note in just about everything but MySQL you would need to use CASE

```
   SUM ( CASE WHEN raction > 0 AND .... THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / ....
```

Comment: Does that actually work in MySQL? I would have naturally used the function form of `IF()` but if I don't have to then I won't bother in future...

Comment: Thanks for this, although 'reporter' isn't defined, and that's the problem I ran into when I tried to do it myself. It has to pull the report, then check of the people reported it, who has the best percentage

Comment: Oh I see. Well its kinda hard to understand what it is you want. Can you give some sample data and sample output. [Here's a webapp](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) that can help with creating the samples

Comment: I edited my post and added a better description of what I want to accomplish under the table